# "two other methods" vs "other two methods"?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

for example,

> 1. I want *two other* methods.
> 2. I want *other two* methods.

Which one above is correct ?

If both are correct, what is the difference? What is the target noun of "two" and "other" assuming they are both adjective?

If only one is correct, is it due to adjective-order-restriction?

Comment: As far as I know, we don't say *other two methods*, but we say *the other two methods*. *Two other methods* is also common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grammatically correct one is

> I want two other methods.

This implies that the two other methods, combined with the original method, **are not the *only* appropriate methods. The asker is thinking that the methods you already told him/her about aren't adequate enough, and wants *two more* methods.**

"other" should have some modifier or quantifier or the definite article preceding it, so your second sentence is ungrammatical.

> I want **the** other two methods.

This means two (contradictory!) things:

- that the person wants **the other two methods *out of some total amount.***
- that the person **doesn't want your currently selected method**, but rather he/she wants the other two methods out of those total.

You'll have to tell which is which by context.

To go off-topic:

> I want every other thing.
>
> Come back some other time.
>
> I hate that other car.

Comment: Just a sidenote - to me, if you say "I want the other two methods," then this means you want the other two methods out of some total amount where the total amount is implied to be however many you have already + 2. "I want two other methods," however, doesn't give any info about how many total methods there are.

Comment: If I say "I want two more methods.", this doesn't imply that I don't want the original method(s). But when I say "I want two other methods", this means the original method(s) is/are not the method I want. Am I correct?

Comment: @user2720402 I completely missed that meaning! Adding.